# How to supply images with Android application

Tags: android

I need to make an application, which will be a gallery of several pictures, supplied with the application when downloading app from Play store.
Could you suggest how this is best done in the future to facilitate the addition of new images?
I know how to do to gallery took the images from a folder on your device, but how to put these images together with the application from Play Store? We need them as a resource to unpack?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put all the image in the drawable folder then the application is going to be very big. I would suggest putting the images on a image hosting cdn like cloudinary then use an image downloader to pick the images from the url and cache them on the device like Picasso or Universal Image Loader. Also you dont want to be shipping updates just because you want to add a few images.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 basic options.

Download images from internet on runtime - supplied by your server which you can control and therefore add new images without the need of updating the application.

Or you can just put images into your `/drawable` folder within app and every time you add new image there you update your app on play store.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways to do it:
(1) Put the pictures to web server. The apps can download the new picture from web server and store to device's local memory.
(2) Put the images to /Asset folder and submit app update to Google Play when you want to add more pictures to the Apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean as a resource to unpack, but the simplest option is to include them as drawables.

If you do not want to do that, you can include them in the assets or raw resources directories. Assets is often used for some images raw might be used if you were for instance including some other format to unpack as you said, bit that comes with its own issues.